# Accessibility: Shifting focus from button to nested span – good idea?

Tags: html, focus, accessibility

On a responsive website, I have a button for small screens that opens the site's main navigation menu. Inside that button there is a `<span>` that displays an icon using CSS.

For design reasons, I hide the text content of the button but keep it accessible for screen-reader users:

```
<button class="menu-operator button">
    <span class="visuallyhidden">Open menu</span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
</button>
```

From a design point of view, the button is not visible as a button (no background-color, border or anything). To still support users with a visual clue on focus, I am thinking about making the button non-focusable and shifting focus to the icon span which I then can style with CSS `:focus`.

So basically this:

```
<button class="menu-operator button" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="visuallyhidden">Open menu</span>
    <span class="icon" tabindex="0"></span>
</button>
```

Is it advisable to do so? Will I introduce more problems than I solve with this idea?

In the past I've heard bad things about "stealing focus", but while testing my idea with OS X Voice Over I was surprised how good it works, so I am a bit unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen reader will read an action "open menu" and you won't be able to click. Strange behavior.

You should use `title` and `aria-label` attributes on the button to give the screen reader an alternative, and keep the button focusable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!